# Не выполняется условие при одновременном использовании resize и scroll

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Суть проблемы. Есть код при изменении размеров окна браузера а так же при скролле меняются некоторые css свойства. Проблема в том что при уменьшении ширины браузера с 768 и более на размер менее 767 и одновременном скролле нижняя часть кода не выполняется

```
else{
        $(".wrapper_nav").css('position','relative');
        $(".logo_dark").css('display','block');
        $(".logo").css('display','none');
    };
```

Вот весь код

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
        var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (width > 767) {   
        $(".wrapper_nav").css('position','fixed');
        $(".list_mobnav").css('display','none');
        $('.wrapper_nav').removeClass("wrapper_nav-white");
        $(window).scroll(function(){ 
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20 ){
                $(".wrapper_nav").addClass("wrapper_nav-white").fadeIn('fast');
                $(".logo_dark").css('display','block');
                $(".logo").css('display','none');
                $(".parent_item-big").css('color','black');
            } else {
                $(".wrapper_nav").removeClass("wrapper_nav-white").fadeIn('fast');
                $(".logo_dark").css('display','none');
                $(".logo").css('display','block');
                $(".parent_item-big").css('color','white');
            };   
        }).trigger('scroll');
    }else{
        $(".wrapper_nav").css('position','relative');
        $(".logo_dark").css('display','block');
        $(".logo").css('display','none');
    };   
}).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень странным образом написан код.

1. При изменении размеров окна вешается обработчик на скорол (так делать не правильно, т.к. за одно перемещение границы окна у вас повешаются десятки таких обработчиков)
2. Зачем вешать событие и тут же вызывать событие? `.trigger('scroll')`

Поправил ваш код, попробуйте запустить. Может заработает

```js
// алгоримт действий при изменении размеров окна
function onResize() {
  var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (width > 767) {
    $(".list_mobnav").css('display','none');
    $(".wrapper_nav")
      .removeClass("wrapper_nav-white")
      .css('position','fixed');
  } else {
    $(".wrapper_nav").css('position','relative');
    $(".logo_dark").css('display','block');
    $(".logo").css('display','none');
  }
}

// алгоритм на прокрутку
function onScroll() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $(".wrapper_nav").addClass("wrapper_nav-white").fadeIn('fast');
    $(".logo_dark").css('display','block');
    $(".logo").css('display','none');
    $(".parent_item-big").css('color','black');
  } else {
    $(".wrapper_nav").removeClass("wrapper_nav-white").fadeIn('fast');
    $(".logo_dark").css('display','none');
    $(".logo").css('display','block');
    $(".parent_item-big").css('color','white');
  }
}

// обработчики вешаются один раз
$(window).scroll(onScroll);
$(window).resize(onResize);
```

Comment: Проблема не исчезла. При изменении размеров окна нужно имитировать скролл что бы стили обновились. Поэтому триггер скрола стоит внутри ресайза. И основная проблема не устранилась всё так же не работает.

Comment: А так же мне не нужно вызывать функцию onScroll постоянно а только при размере экранов больше 767.